# Returning value from UIDatePicker when multiple UITextFields are present

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uidatepicker, uitextfielddelegate

I have multiple `UITextField` and some of them will use the 'UIDatePicker'. How can I return the value from the UIDatePicker without having to code `textField.text = formatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)` in the `datePickerChanged` function?

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    switch textField.tag {

        //tag = 3 is the text field that needs the date
    case 3:
        let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        textField.inputView = datePicker
        datePicker.addTarget(self, action: "datePickerChanged:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
        //textField.text = value returned from datePickerChanged
    default: break
    }
}

func datePickerChanged(datePicker: UIDatePicker) {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
    let dateTextValue = formatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)
    // how can I return (dateTextValue)?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a variable called `currentTextField`, and in your case statement assign `textField` to `currentTextField`.  Then your datePickerChanged(_:) function could use `currentTextField` to set the date.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Hmm okay, how should I go about initializing the `currentTextField`? Maybe I'm not quite understanding

Comment: @Sami, `var currentTextField: UITextField?`  That initializes currentTextField to nil.  Whoops--it shouldn't be an @IBOutlet.

Comment: You might even be able to declare the variable as an implicitly unwrapped optional: `var currentTextField: UITextField!`, which will make it easier to deal with the variable.

Comment: Yep - this worked and let me keep the function generic. Thanks :)

Comment: @Sami,  It seems strange to me that you are adding the target inside `textFieldDidBeginEditing(_:)`.  So every time the user begins editing the same textField you want to add the target?   Why not add all the targets for the textFields inside a ViewController's loadView()/viewDidLoad()?

Comment: A tutorial said to do that--blind following the blind I see. 

If I migrate to putting it in the viewDidLoad could I avoid having to use my `tag` approach?

Comment: @Sami, Yes--presumably you know which UITextFields you want to use the DatePicker with, but if you have a lot of TextFields you may end up having to usie a similar construct to loop over them and pick out which ones you need to add targets to.   But the advantage of doing that is when the user keeps selecting different textFileds--your code won't repeatedly add the target.